# Why I'm getting InvocationTargetException error when I want to add new polygon on Nutiteq?

Tags: java, android, clip, nutiteq

I'm computing some area and I want to draw a polygon on the area I have computed. But I'm getting this error

[image: this]

I've tracked the error with debug and I've seen that program just cant pass this line in the middle.

[image: img2]

I've declared everthing as described in [Editable Carto DB](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Editable-CartoDB-Layer) page described. But It just stops when the point style is defining.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please always give full trace of the exception, not just one line. `InvocationTargetException` does not really mean anything specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no need to call `setBitmap()` for the style, and pointMarker bitmap is anyway default bitmap for points. Just remove this. I suspect the `pointMarker` could be null.